# Can I develop iBeacon application with the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I was trying to develop an iOS application to accept iBeacon notifications. It's handy if the iOS simulator can use BlueTooth capability of MacBook to accept an iBeacon message.

Is there a way that iOS simulator can accept notification from an external real iBeacon device?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you cannot get any CoreLocation iBeacon events or CoreBluetooth events from the iOS simulator.  This makes it of very limited use in developing iBeacon applications.

While you will certainly need a real physical device with iOS7 and BLE (iPhone 4S+) for testing, you can still do lots of you development on the simulator.  You simply need to build "back doors" or insert test code to trigger your iBeacon events. (There is nothing to prevent you from calling your CoreLocation delegate methods explicitly from test code.)  I find that getting the iBeacon part of the code working is about 10 percent of the job.  The rest of the app development can be done in the simulator.

Comment: are you sure this is correct? i do recognize that you're an expert in this area, but I'm sure that I've read that you can use a USB bluetooth adapter with the ios simulator. Perhaps something like this:

http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B007GFX0PY/ref=s9_simh_se_p147_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=auto-no-results-center-1&pf_rd_r=1CZW1BC6TSJWA8RB8N2A&pf_rd_t=301&pf_rd_p=478281791&pf_rd_i=B00A0CBOTE

Comment: @brad-parks, I would *love* to be wrong on this one!  I have tried both my built-in bluetooth and that exact USB adapter on my Mac and I can sadly report that they don't allow the simulator to get bluetooth events.  I don't think it has anything to do with the adapter -- the simulator simply does not implement the bluetooth stack.  Unfortunately, I have never heard of anybody say they have been able to do this.